# Untick the 'Open Safe Files' preference in Safari with Terminal

Tags: terminal, safari, security

After all the [fuss](http://www.macworld.com/article/159995/2011/05/trolls_straw_men.html#lsrc.mod_rel) over Mac Defender, I thought it might be a good idea to disable the open safe files option in safari for the users in our network. I'd like to do this with the 'Send Unix Command' via Remote Desktop.

[image: Safari Preferences]

How can I use terminal to disable this preference in Safari?

Comment: Also a really good idea to uncheck this everywhere as a new version "Mac Guard" now can run as a standard user, no need for admin password for installing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the defaults application to change the preference for this using the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari AutoOpenSafeDownloads 0
```